# Discord.js presenceUpdate firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```html
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  if (!newPresence.activities) return false;
  newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
    if (activity.type == 'STREAMING') {
      //Do stuff if someone starts a stream
    }
```

I've been developing a Discord bot for my friend's Discord server which automatically notifies, if someone starts streaming. Everything was working fine and dandy, but then yesterday something that I cannot comprehend happened.

A person started streaming and the bot saw that, so it sent a message notifying people like it should. However, that same stream was nearing its end, when the bot decided "I'm gonne send 2 more notifications that the stream has started". These notifications were minute apart from each other.

Could someone please help me with this issue? I've provided a small code snippet from my code which checks if a person starts streaming. Is there a way to stop the bot from sending any more notifications if the user has been streaming? I'd only like the bot to notify about this once when someone starts streaming, not multiple times concerning one specific stream.

Comment: Your question includes a lot of greeting and thanks, this is normally not supposed to be done on here

Comment: Ahh my mistake! First time doing this, so I had no idea. Will keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`presenceUpdate` would also emit, when someone goes into dnd or idle, as well as, when switching game.

So your case could be that the streamer either went idle and online, or switched application wich updated his activites and so their presence.

A possible fix would be to have a database ( or a temporary collection ) which tracks the active streamers so it only sends one message per stream and then waits until the stream is stopped.

Comment: That makes 100% sense now that you described the issue. I tried to fork on the code some more, but I cannot seem to find a way to isolate the checking to streaming only. Now I know that there is no way to stop presenceUpdate from happening, so I suppose there would be a way to check if a specific user is streaming, but not launch the message to the channel in case Discord switches them to "idle" for example?

Comment: @torastrengel A possible fix would be to have a database ( or a temporary collection ) wich tracks the active streamers so it only sends one message.